# Is there a way to control the categories displayed in the iOS Storage Usage display for my app?

Tags: ios

The display for most apps in "Settings > General > Usage" just shows a number for "Documents & Data" and one button to delete the whole app.

However, the "Music" entry in that list presents a UI with categories and an "edit" button to optionally delete some data and not all.

Is there a way to get a similar UI for a third-party app?
Because doing this is useful but not common, it'd be nice to avoid having this UI in the app itself.